# Redirect IO of process to Windows socket

Tags: c++, windows, winsock, winsock2

I am new to winsock, I tried to write a server socket that accepts new connection, then it calls an external executable file. How can we redirect the stdin and stdout of the external executable file to the client socket which has been accepted. I googled and found the code below but it does not work. The new process was created successfully but the client could not receive any data from the new process. I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2008 Express edition. Any helps and comments are appreciated. Thank a lot!

the server

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

        WSADATA wsaData;
        int iResult;

        // Initialize Winsock
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

        struct addrinfo *result = NULL, *ptr = NULL, hints;

        ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof (hints));
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
        hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

        // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
        iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

        SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

         // Setup the TCP listening socket
        iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if ( listen( ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN ) == SOCKET_ERROR ) {
            printf( "Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        SOCKET ClientSocket;

        ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

        // Accept a client socket
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        STARTUPINFO si;
        memset( &si, 0, sizeof( si ) );
        si.cb = sizeof( si );
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

        si.hStdInput = (HANDLE)ClientSocket;
        si.hStdOutput = (HANDLE)ClientSocket;
        si.hStdError = (HANDLE)ClientSocket;

        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

        TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\hello.exe");

        if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
            printf("create process successfully\n");
            DWORD i = WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );
            printf("%8x\n", i);
        }


        CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
        CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
        closesocket( ClientSocket );
        WSACleanup();

}
```

the client

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        WSADATA wsaData;
        SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                        *ptr = NULL,
                        hints;
        char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
        int iResult;
        int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

        // Initialize Winsock
        iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

        ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
        hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
        hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
        hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

        // Resolve the server address and port
        iResult = getaddrinfo("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

        // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
        for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {
            // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
            ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
                ptr->ai_protocol);
            if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
                printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            // Connect to server.
            iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                closesocket(ConnectSocket);
                ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(result);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Receive until the peer closes the connection
        do {

            iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if ( iResult > 0 )
                printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            else if ( iResult == 0 )
                printf("Connection closed\n");
            else
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

        } while( iResult > 0 );

        // cleanup
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();

        return 0;
}
```

external program hello.cpp

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("hello world!\n");       
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows treats almost everything as a `HANDLE`.  Sockets, which aren't kernel objects, are an exception, and they can't be used for redirection.  You'll need to use a pipe, and if you need to send data to/from a socket, you'll need a helper process to copy data between the pipe and socket.

Have a look at `netcat` source code for the win32 version (if you can find it), it does pretty much exactly socket <-> stdin and stdout forwarding.

Answer (score 15):

Actually, you can redirect IO to sockets. Just make sure you open the socket with WSASocket instead of socket(), and do NOT specify the WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.

The reason for this is a bit involved. Any "Standard Handles" that you supply to CreateProcess for I/O redirection must be non-overlapped (i.e, do not support overlapped I/O). sockets on Windows are opened overlapped when created with socket() and non-overlapped if created as above with WSASocket.

Also make sure you set bInheritHandles to TRUE in the StartupInfo

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced my socket call with socket = WSASocket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, 0) (I was already doing WSAStartup etc) and it just works :)

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  There is no need to use intermediate pipes.  The information provided in this answer was useful for adaptation to a general purpose CreateProcess() command-line utility: https://github.com/cubiclesoft/createprocess-windows

Answer (score 4):

*Overlapped* sockets (such as created with `socket()`) cannot be used directly for I/O redirection.

When launching the external process, use `CreatePipe()` instead to create anonymous pipes for the redirected STDIN/OUT/ERR handles of the process, then use `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()` (or equivilents) with `send()` and `recv()` to manually proxy the data between the socket and the process yourself via the pipes.

In other words, when data arrives to the socket, read the data from the socket and write it to the STDIN pipe.  When the process outputs data, read from the STDOUT/ERR pipes and write it to the socket.

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct to say that socket handles cannot be used for redirected IO to child processes.  We do it all the time for CGI in our web server code. We don't use named or unnamed pipes, or intermediary processes.

a_mole is correct.  You just need non-overlapped sockets.

You can either use WSASocket, or if you created the socket already with socket (or can't use WSASocket on your target OS, e.g. Pre Windows 7 SP1) you can use setsockopt to set the current thread's SO_OPENTYPE to SO_SYNCHRONOUS_NONALERT