# redirecting std handles of child process to parent's sockets on windows

Tags: windows, sockets, io-redirection

I've searched the web all over and haven't found a suitable answer for this.
I'm fixing legacy code which was written for windows server 2003 or earlier versions. In some point in the code the main program accepts connections from a server socket, runs DuplicateHandle on the accepted sockets and sets them as in,out and err handles of a child process it invokes with CreateProcess (the child process is an external program such as cmd.exe) (One of the parameters of CreateProcess accepts the std handles structure).

This code doesn't work anymore on newer versions of Windows (Server 2008 and above is what I use now), Microsoft decided to not allow sockets be duplicated this way and recommeneds using WSADuplicateSocket. The problem here is that this function requires the process id of the child process, but in the sequence I mentioned above the child process is created only after the handles are duplicated. I have the luxury of creating the child process as suspended but I'm not sure I can replace the std handles after the process was created already.

Is there any recommended approach to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Unlike other platforms, on Windows you cannot really use sockets directly as redirected I/O for processes.  So don't even try it at all.  Instead, use `CreatePipe()` to create anonymous pipes for the redirected I/O ([example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)), then use standard pipe/socket I/O functions to read data from the socket and write it to the STDIN pipe, and to read data from the STDOUT/ERR pipes and write it to the socket.

Comment: Thanks Remy, is there a way to link between the pipe and the socket or do i have to create a thread that does that transfers the data from and to the pipes?

Comment: There is nothing to link them at the API level, you have to manage it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect IO of process to Windows socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993119/redirect-io-of-process-to-windows-socket)